# Binding ListView's GridView to List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: wpf, gridview, data-binding

Here's how I am making my GridView:

The ListView will contain `Entry` objects which looks like this:

```
public class Entry
{
    public Entry(BitmapImage icon = null, List<EntryKeyValuePair> entryKeyValuePairs = null)
    {
        Icon = icon;
        EntryKeyValuePairs = entryKeyValuePairs ?? new List<EntryKeyValuePair>();
    }

    public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }
    public List<EntryKeyValuePair> EntryKeyValuePairs { get; }
}
```

`EntryKeyValuePair` is just a `KeyValuePair<string,string>` where `Key` is the Column and `Value` is the value of the column. I used a List of KeyValuePair because I want to preserve insertion order. Anyway, here's how I am constructing the GridView.

```
GridView = new GridView();
foreach (Column column in Category.Columns.Where(c => c.IsVisibleInTable)) {
    var gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn {
        Header = column.Name,
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding($"EntryKeyValuePairs[{column.Name}].Value")
    };
    GridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);
}
```

I don't know what binding to set in DisplayMemberBinding. The above binding would work if `EntryKeyValuePairs` was a dictionary. But in my case it is not.

If I had access to the data object somehow, I could do

```
DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding($"EntryKeyValuePairs[{entry.EntryKeyValuePairs.FindIndex(p => p.Key == column.Name)}].Value")
```

How can I access the current Data Object which the ListView is holding while binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I used the `GridViewColumn`'s `CellTemplateSelector` so that I can get a reference to the `ListView`s bound object. Here is how the `CellTemplateSelector` looks like. I had to create the DataTemplates in code.

```
class GridViewCellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private readonly string _columnName;

    public GridViewCellTemplateSelector(string columnName)
    {
        _columnName = columnName;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)item;
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate {
            DataType = typeof (Entry)
        };

        var stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);

        var text = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        text.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding($"EntryKeyValuePairs[{entry.EntryKeyValuePairs.FindIndex(p => p.Key == _columnName)}].Value"));

        stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(text);

        dataTemplate.VisualTree = stackPanelFactory;

        return dataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Instead of DisplayMemberBinding, I used this TemplateSelector:

```
CellTemplateSelector = new GridViewCellTemplateSelector(column.Name)
```

All good. Hope this helps someone :) I still hope to see a better solution than this.